# Lineageos bacon build failed

Tags: build, ninja, lineageos

I am trying to build LineageOS 17.1 bacon based on the steps here: https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/bacon/build

All steps until the below failure have been successful. Everything is the latest leading to `LINEAGE_VERSION=17.1-20210324-UNOFFICIAL-bacon`

`brunch bacon` returns the following failure. This is my first android build, web search did not yield anything useful on how to fix this. Currently, I am clueless, any help/suggestions on how to fix this are very welcome.

```
[ 75% 372/496] including system/sepolicy/Android.mk ...
system/sepolicy/Android.mk:89: warning: Be careful when using the SELINUX_IGNORE_NEVERALLOWS flag. It does not work in user builds and using it will not stop you from failing CTS.
[100% 496/496] writing build rules ...
build/make/core/Makefile:28: warning: overriding commands for target `out/target/product/bacon/system/vendor/lib/hw/android.hardware.nfc@1.0-impl.so'
build/make/core/base_rules.mk:510: warning: ignoring old commands for target `out/target/product/bacon/system/vendor/lib/hw/android.hardware.nfc@1.0-impl.so'
FAILED: ninja: 'vendor/oppo/msm8974-common/proprietary/vendor/bin/hci_qcomm_init', needed by 'out/target/product/bacon/system/vendor/bin/hci_qcomm_init', missing and no known rule to make it
18:51:33 ninja failed with: exit status 1
```

Could the above error be due to the missing source?:

```
$ ./extract-files.sh 

Cleaning output directory (./../../oppo/msm8974-common/../../../vendor/oppo/msm8974-common/proprietary)..

Extracting 115 files in ./../../oppo/msm8974-common/proprietary-files.txt from adb:

  - vendor/bin/adsprpcd

  - vendor/bin/hci_qcomm_init

    !! vendor/bin/hci_qcomm_init: file not found in source
```

Edit: Answering my own question, one has to run `adb root` on the terminal that guides you want needs to be done on the phone. This can be closed. #lineageos-dev is the place to ask such a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, one has to run `adb root` on the terminal that guides you to do what needs to be done on the phone. This can be closed. #lineageos-dev is the place to ask such a question.